# Why do my ReactJS changes disappear on refreshing the page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm new to React and I'm trying to render a list of Pokemons.

I'm fetching the pokemon names from a local file and then using those names to trigger HTTP calls to my backend server, to get the pokemon images. Here's my code so far:

```
function PokemonList(props) {
  const [pokemonList, setPokemonList] = useState([]);
  const [isFetched, setIsFetched] = useState(false);
  const [renderedList, setRenderedList] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(raw)
      .then((r) => r.text())
      .then((text) => {
        setPokemonList(text.split("\n"));
        setIsFetched(true);
      });
  }, []);

  // I believe this is to blame, but I don't know why. On refresh, pokemonList becomes empty
  useEffect(() => {
    setRenderedList(populateRenderedList(pokemonList));
  }, []);

  return !isFetched ? null : (
    <div className="list">
      {renderedList}
      <PaginationBar listSize={renderedList.length} list={renderedList} />
    </div>
  );
}


function populateRenderedList(pokemonList) {
  let pokemonAPI = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/";
  const temp = [];

  console.log(pokemonList); 

  pokemonList.forEach((pokemonName) => {
    let renderedPokemon = (
      <a className="pokemonLink" href={pokemonAPI + pokemonName.toLowerCase()}>
        <PokemonDiv name={pokemonName.toLowerCase()} />
        <h3>{pokemonName}</h3>
      </a>
    );

    temp.push(renderedPokemon);
  });

  return temp;
}
```

As I have commented on the code, the 'pokemonList' renders fine when I make any changes to the PokemonList function. But the moment I refresh my page, 'pokemonList' becomes empty. Why is that?

I previously was not using 'useState' to populate my 'renderedList' list. So I believe the problem is happening because I'm using 'useState' , but I don't know why that's happening.

I had tried making 'renderedList' not a state, but I had to, for I am thinking about passing it as props to another child component, in order to change it's state.

Comment: You need to add the pokemonList variable to the dependencies array of the useEffect.

Comment: @LindaPaiste, you're a lifesaver!! Can you explain why I needed to do that?

Comment: It's the React "way". Read up on `useEffect`. Essentially, when you define `[]` you are saying "run this once when the component is mounted." Well, what is `pokemonList` when the component mounted? It's an empty array ([]). When adding `pokemonList` to the array list, you say "re-run this effect any time `pokemonList` changes". Hope that clear things up!